# Display block moving entire body section

Tags: html, css, block, display

I have a webpage with an image and a section of text which I'm trying to stack in a vertical line. I figured adding display: block; to .about div would be the appropriate way of doing this. It gives me the vertical stack that I want, but impacts the overall layout of the page. At first I thought it was pulling the header section down the page, but when I inspected the page, it seems as if this command is actually shifting the entire body section down the page. Not sure what is causing this.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo"> <h1>
        <div id="header_title">
            Name
        </div></h1> </a>
        <div id="header_border"></div>
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="selected" >About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="subNav">
                    <a>Portfolio</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="writing_samples.html">Writing Samples</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="about_div">
            <img src="img/1935323_10153090821883239_4407778661294134622_n.jpg"  class="profile-photo">
        </div>
        <div class="about_div">
            <h3 id="about_me">About Me</h3>
            <p id="about_me_info">
                Text
            </p>
            <p id="about_me_info">
                More Text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p>
            &copy; 2016 My Name.
        </p>
    </div>


</body>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', open sans;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 18%;
}

.about_div {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.about_div img {
    margin-left: 125px;
}

.about_div h3 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.about_div p {
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.profile-photo {
    max-width: 350px;
    border-radius: 100%; /* adds rounded corners to an element */
}

#about_me {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#about_me_info {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

How header spacing should look (with inline-block) [image]

How header spacing actually looks when applying display: block [image]

Note that this isn't technically a problem with the header, but rather the entire body section is shifting downward in the second example.

Comment: can you post an image and a fiddle? I tried it with your code but I didn't get layout correctly.

Comment: I am checking your code. everything is line up to the left of the window. I'm not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: i've added images for reference

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:block` from '.about_div' and add `display:flex` to '#wrapper'

Comment: doing this shifts the body back to its normal position but doesn't allow for vertical alignment of the image and text sections (as in the second image)

Comment: you just have to add margin-top to the wrapper to add space between the header, and the image and text div.